# how can we get comments of photo

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-fql

I'm working on c#,.net web application using Facebook API for retrieving data from my own account.
I need to fetch all the comments which is posted on my album or photo, i tried the following fql query
 but it returns empty string.

```
string strGetComments = api.Fql.Query("SELECT  post_id, fromid, time, text, 
       id FROM comment WHERE object_id IN
       (SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN 
       ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=" + UserID + "))");
```

I be very thankful if anyone can give me some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the web request in fiddler to make sure that it is well formed there? You can then start fiddling with it / executing it and see if you can fix it that way. Then come back to the API to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change UserID to maybe username I don't see UserID in none of the fql .tables. if you can give some of you c# code so we can look at it. I believe to run a fql you have to do something that starts like this.

```
string strGetComments = https//www.facebook.com/?fql=
```

[Facebook reference page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Hope this helps.